# Solr facet behavior

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj, facet, solrcloud

So I'm running in to a problem with facetting in Solr. When I query for something, say `sourcecode:WOS`, I get what you would expect, like so:
[image: q=sourcecode:WOS]
This looks fine.

However, if I now try to FACET on this field instead, I get this:
[image: facetting on sourcecode]
As you can see, I now have 4 entries for each sourcecode, and all of them have some weird combination of symbols prepended to them:

```
<int name="C¨4C1">1433755</int>
<int name="C¨4C1">1433755</int>
<int name="¨4c1">1433755</int>
<int name="¨4c1">1433755</int>
```

It seems like some unicode character are added when I facet for sourcecode, which is a `solr.TextField`.
Has anyone ever encountered this issue before?

Thanks,
Rasmus Edvardsen

Comment: What is the complete definition of your field?

Comment: It is of type `iqlunstemmed`. It's a custom fieldType, that looks like this:
`<fieldType name="iqlunstemmed" class="solr.TextField">
          <analyzer type="index">
              <charFilter class="uk.co.flax.infomedia.iql.analysis.HTMLCharFilterFactory"/>
              <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
              <filter class="uk.co.flax.infomedia.solr.IQLUnstemmedFilterFactory"/>
          </analyzer>
      </fieldType>`

I know this is of no use to you as you don't know what the custom packages do. But yea, I guess I have to look down in there.

Comment: I'm guessing those custom packages attach metadata to each token (and inside the token itself, instead of using the payload functionality which might have been added later than your Solr version), and what you're seeing is that metadata. You can work around this by creating a separate field for faceting and facet filtering instead, where you keep the original token as you want it.

Comment: Great, thanks @MatsLindh.
Our Solr version is 5.4, and we do actually have separate fields (fs_*/f_*). Sorry for not giving this information, but I wanted an answer that wasn't colored from this knowledge. I will make a note of this, and continue onwards.
Thanks again